# How to retain internal connections (existing worksheet) in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am having an Excel Master File, **v1** and the data source for my list boxes and multi-list boxes are pointing to an external workbook, **v2** instead of internally.

As a result, my conditional formatting logic, based on and data validation sources don't work.

The conditional formatting should look up local values, but instead look at V2. The error **#REF** appears instead of the range of cells **A1:B2** which should originally appear

[image]

I have tried the following:

1. Removing Existing Connection
   [image]
2. Change the Connection file to be **this worksheet (v1)**
   [image]

After pressing refresh, none of the above solutions work.

3. I have tried to change source to **v1**and break link, since apparently this is supposed to make the list boxes **retain** their original references.

[image]

I am unable to do so, even after having **v2** literally open. This error message appears:

[image]

So my questions are:

1. How do I prevent the references  from automatically being updated when I send my Masterfile to another user?

2.Is there any code to **prevent** automatically changing the references from internal (this workbook) to external (**v2**?)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A master list will be created in one workbook, and drop down lists in a different workbook will be based on that list. The most IMPORTANT is for the drop down list to work, the workbook which contains the list must be open, in the same instance of Excel, when you use the drop down lists.

Comment: "A master list will be created in one workbook, and drop down lists in a different workbook will be based on that list."  Actually, the master list is stored in a hidden worksheet in the *same* workbook.  therefore, it is always open.

Comment: In that case Un-hide the Sheet select the Master List and provide a NAME to it,,, then create Drop Down in other WBook and use full path as reference,, =C:\folder\MasterWb.xls!MasterListName. Here MasterListMName is the Named Range in Master Wbook!!

Comment: thanks! but I do not want to create a local reference on C drive. Since the Master file will be shared around to others, it will not work if it points to my local C drive

Comment: Then use Shared Folder over the Network or Server's Folder!

Comment: we do not want to use shared folder

Comment: ,, *Since the Master file will be shared around to others*,, and you have written that you don't like Shared folder,, then the ultimate option is Local one!!